# Heap corruption in simple C++ program

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, valgrind

I wrote a simple C++ program, here’s the code:

```cpp
// Вариант 72, задача 2.18
#include <iostream>

#define lint long long int

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

void input(lint arr[], lint arrLen) {
    for (lint i = 0; i < arrLen; ++i) {
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
}

void output(lint arr[], lint arrLen) {
    for (lint i = 0; i < arrLen; ++i) {
        cout << "newArr[" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << '\n';
    }
}

bool isNumberInArray(const lint arr[], lint arrLen, lint number) {
    bool isNumberPresent = false;
    for (lint i = 0; i < arrLen; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == number) isNumberPresent = true;
    }
    return isNumberPresent;
}

void process(const lint arr[], lint arrLen, lint newArr[], lint &newArrLen, lint m, lint M) {
    newArrLen = 0;
    for (lint i = M; i >= m; --i) {
        if (!isNumberInArray(arr, arrLen, i)) {
            newArr[newArrLen] = i;
            ++newArrLen;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    lint arrLen, m, M;

    cout << "Enter m\n> ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Enter M\n> ";
    cin >> M;
    cout << "Enter array length\n> ";
    cin >> arrLen;

    lint *arr = new lint[arrLen];

    cout << "Enter array elements:\n";
    input(arr, arrLen);

    lint *newArr = new lint[arrLen], newArrLen;

    process(arr, arrLen, newArr, newArrLen, m, M);

    cout << "\nResults:\n";
    output(newArr, newArrLen);

    delete[] arr;
    delete[] newArr;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it using MSVC (x86 | Debug) and run it, it normally works and produces the desired result, but after execution shows the following error:
[image: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED]

I tried to compile a program under WSL using g++ and debug it with Valgrind. Here is what I got:

```
root@seiba-laptop : /mnt/c/Users/saber-nyan/source/repos/Project1/Project1
[130] # g++ ./main.cpp -O0 -ggdb -o ./main

root@seiba-laptop : /mnt/c/Users/saber-nyan/source/repos/Project1/Project1
[0] # valgrind ./main
==316== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==316== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==316== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==316== Command: ./main
==316==
==316== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
Enter m
> 1
Enter M
> 5
Enter array length
> 2
Enter array elements:
arr[0] = 4
arr[1] = 2
==316== Invalid write of size 8
==316==    at 0x1093A4: process(long long const*, long long, long long*, long long&, long long, long long) (main.cpp:34)
==316==    by 0x1094E4: main (main.cpp:57)
==316==  Address 0x4d60560 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==316==    at 0x483850F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
==316==    by 0x1094BA: main (main.cpp:55)
==316==

Results:
newArr[0] = 5
newArr[1] = 3
==316== Invalid read of size 8
==316==    at 0x1092B7: output(long long*, long long) (main.cpp:18)
==316==    by 0x10950A: main (main.cpp:60)
==316==  Address 0x4d60560 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==316==    at 0x483850F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
==316==    by 0x1094BA: main (main.cpp:55)
==316==
newArr[2] = 1
==316==
==316== HEAP SUMMARY:
==316==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==316==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 74,784 bytes allocated
==316==
==316== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==316==
==316== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==316== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: don't use C-style arrays in C++. Don't use raw pointers that own memory in C++. Don't use explicit memory allocation in C++. You seem to write a C program sparkled with some C++ `cin` / `cout`. Use standard containers and, if needed, smart pointers.

Comment: @bolov If I could, I would do that - but, unfortunately, this is a laboratory work, and using arrays in the C style is said in the task.

Comment: When you get such an error assume your *code* is wrong, not the compiler. In any case you aren't supposed to use raw pointers or `new` in C++. Use `lint newArr[arrLen]` to define an array at least, or use `std::vector` which will actually worn you when you try to write beyond its boundaries. Use smart pointers like `unique_ptr` instead of `new` and `delete`

Comment: @saber-nyan then don't ask about *C++* or use C++ constructs like `cin`. Tag the question with `c`. `lint newArr[arrLen]` works in C too

Comment: @saber-nyan in any case, nothing prevents you from using `std::vector` to find the problem and then replacing it with a C-style array. Just don't hand-in the code with `vector`

Comment: As an aside, you might want to give this link to your instructor: [Stop teaching C.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) By "forcing" you to learn "the C way" of doing things first, he's putting you through lots of unnecessary misery. The whole point of C++ is making these things (manual memory management etc.) *go away*.

Comment: @DevSolar You misunderstood what is meant in this video. It is an advice not to try teaching C++ starting teaching the C part of C++; not "stop teaching C" in general.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: I very much did *not* misunderstand that video; as you can read from my comment, I am *talking* about learning C++. "Stop learning C" is the title of the lecture picked by the lecturer, Kate Gregory. That it should not be constructed as a bashing of learning C is what she is talking about in the first few minutes. But the OP is setting out to learn C++, and his instructor is holding him back by forcing him to use the C subset of the langugage. I wanted to point out the falacy in that, and Mrs. Gregory does a much better job at explaining than I could.

Comment: @DevSolar What is the most fun, I already know Java and Python and, in principle, could study C++ myself, if that was interesting to me.

Comment: @saber-nyan: I'd say that would be better for you, and would love to recommend a good [textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for you, but unfortunately I haven't had one in hand yet that followed Kate Gregory's advice, so I cannot make recommendations from own experience. (I learned it "the hard way" back in my days.) But give that advice to your instructor nevertheless. He/She's a multiplier, and *should* know better...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I understand is that you try to construct a new array containing values not present in the original one. In your case you first built [4,2] and tried to build [5,3,1] because values in between M=5,m=1 not present in [4,2] are [5,3,1].

Your problem is that you first built `newArr` as an array of length 2 (the same length as `arr`). But you can't put 3 values in an array of size 2.

```
==316== Invalid write of size 8
==316==    at 0x1093A4: process(long long const*, long long, long long*, long long&, long long, long long) (main.cpp:34)
==316==    by 0x1094E4: main (main.cpp:57)
==316==  Address 0x4d60560 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==316==    at 0x483850F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
==316==    by 0x1094BA: main (main.cpp:55)
```

`Invalid write of size 8` means you tried to write a `long long int` at some bad address.

`Address 0x4d60560 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd` means that valgrind detected that your bad write was at the end of an memory chunk of size 16, exactly the size of an array of two `long long int`s.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your newArr does not necessarily have enough space to hold all the long long ints; That depends on the values of M and m which determine how many iterations would the for loop in process(...) go through and the values stored in arr.

To fix it, in this line here:

- lint *newArr = new lint[arrLen], newArrLen;

Instead of arrLen amount of new lints, allocate (M - m + 1).

You should also make sure that  M > m